# HWIOAuthBundle : Redirecting to localhost after login

Tags: symfony, redirect, hwioauthbundle

i've installed HWIOAuthBundle and after login success i would like to redirect to localhost. ( i've configured apache to work on localhost ). 
So instead of  `http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/` after login, i like to go to `http://localhost`

Edited :

here is my config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
http_client:
    verify_peer: false
connect:
    account_connector: my_user_provider
# name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
firewall_name: main
fosub:
    username_iterations: 30
    properties:
        # these properties will be used/redefined later in the custom FOSUBUserProvider service.
        facebook: facebook_id
        google: google_id
        linkedin: linkedin_id
resource_owners:
    facebook:
        type:                facebook
        client_id:           *******
        client_secret:       ******
        scope:               "email"
        paths:
            email:          email
        options:
            display: popup
    google:
        type:                google
        client_id:           *******
        client_secret:       *******
        scope:               "email"
```

Security.yml

```
 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      ~
        provider:       main
        logout: true
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: /localhost
        remember_me:
            key:        %secret%
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                google:             "/login/check-google"
            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login
            default_target_path: my_app_homepage
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: my_user_provider
```

How can i redirect to localhost using `default_target_path` ?

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I've tried too hard to solve, but couldn't get anywhere near the answer. I've edited my post, hoping to get some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem sovled using `default_target_path: http://localhost/` 
posting solution for help